# How to solve TNS Protocol Adapter error in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle10g, tns

In SQL Plus while logging in showing TNS Protocol Adapter error, also it didn't ask for dbname and username & password during installation.

Comment: What exactly did you install? Was it a database, or a **client**? If the later, it just contains files that allow you access an Oracle database, but it is NOT a database itself.

Comment: It was a database, I have downloaded from oracle official website.

Answer (score 1):

Even I have faced similar problem.  But I resolved it.  Just go services 
Path : press windows+R(keyboard)
Type services.msc and search for Oracle Services in list and right click on it, click on start. 
Just restart the sqlplus with administrator mode.  It will work